# Problems converting netCDF to CSV file using CDO

Tags: csv, netcdf, cdo-climate

*This post is very long because I want to explain better the context.*

My main data source is in netCDF format and I want to convert into CSV file.

For a while, I've been using Python to convert. As an example, I use a netCDF data previously modified (m > mm, hourly > daily) and then converted into a  CSV file. This is how it looks like:

[image]

It can be noted that:

- First row include variable names separated by commas. Second row and up values are delimited by commas too.
- Latitude and longitude values are not rounded.

As shown in the image above is the desired data presentation.

After, I decided to use Climate Data Operator (CDO) because it was more easy to apply some functions. Inside Ubuntu on WSL, I converted netCDF files into CSV ones. These were the codes I used:

**First code**

`cdo -outputtab,date,lat,lon,value era5land_total_precipitation_daily_feb-nov_2017_mm.nc > test-1_tp.csv`

The output data is shown as

[image]

The first row where variable names are located is preceded by "#" when it shouldn't be there. Also, values are delimited by blank spaces.

**Second code**

`cdo -outputtab,date,lat:6,lon:6,value:8 era5land_total_precipitation_daily_feb-nov_2017_mm.nc | grep -v '#' | sed -e 's/   */,/g' >> test-1_tp.csv`

**Third code**

`cdo -outputtab,date,lat:6,lon:6,value:8 era5land_total_precipitation_daily_feb-nov_2017_mm.nc | sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g' > test-1_tp.csv`

Last two lines of code show an equal output

[image]

The problem is partially solved with delimited values by commas although in some observations the last two values are still divided by a blank space. Also, there's no variable names at the top.

**Fourth code**

`cdo -outputtab,date,lat:6,lon:6,value:8 era5land_total_precipitation_daily_feb-nov_2017_mm.nc | awk 'FNR==1{ row=$2","$3","$4","$5; print row } FNR1=1{ row=$1","$2","$3","$4; print row}' > test-1_tp.csv`

The output contains

[image]

The result of the last code is the closest to what I want to obtain except second row in the content of the image needs to be deleted and latitude/longitude values are still rounded. Any Suggestion to obtain a dataset like image 1?

Extra help: does anyone know the meaning of these pieces of codes?

`...| grep -v '#' | sed -e 's/   */,/g'`

`...| sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g'`

`...| awk 'FNR==1{ row=$2","$3","$4","$5; print row } FNR1=1{ row=$1","$2","$3","$4; print row}'`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I asked in another forum the same question and I received the following solution:

`cdo -outputtab,date,lat:6,lon:6,value:8 infile.nc | grep -v '#' | tr -s ' ' | sed -e 's/ /,/g;s/^.//;s/.$//' >> outfile.csv`

Keep in mind

- first row contains generic names of variables: v1, v2, v3 and v4 instead of date, latitude, longitude and tp.
- all values are delimited by commas.